# orderByChild(), limitTo() not working in my angularjs project.?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, angularfire

I wanted to implement **"Querying Data with firebase"** whose documentation was given at fallowing link: "https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html". I started implementing the code as following:

```
getDetail : function() {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
    ref.orderByChild("height").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.key() + " was " + snapshot.val().height + " meters tall");
    })  
},
```

But, I was unable to get the result, in fact an error was produced:

```
TypeError: ref.orderByChild is not a function
 at Object.history.getDetail (history.js:20)
 at Scope.$scope.getDetail (history.js:11)
 at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12332)
 at angular-touch.js:472
 at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14383)
 at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14482)
 at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular-touch.js:471)
 at HTMLButtonElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (jquery.js:4430)
 at HTMLButtonElement.jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4116)
```

Kindly guide me, how can I use these **"Querying Data with firebase"** functions like **"Ordering by a specified child key", Ordering by key name, Ordering by value, Ordering by priority** etc.

My project's firebase version is : **firebase: 2.1.X**

Please help...

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your code on a codepen, plunkr etc ?

Comment: From your comment to @EmmanuelGleizer's answer it seems like your problem is in importing/injecting Firebase/AngularFire. Please *edit* your question to provide a *minimal, complete* example of module/controller. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem, see my [codepen](http://codepen.io/EmmanuelGleizer/pen/VLaKdE?editors=101)

Did you include:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.1.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

[Edited no more relevant]
As specified in https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/quickstart.html *any Firebase URL as a REST endpoint by appending .json to the end of the URL*:

```
 var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json");
```

Comment: Sorry but a new error has occurred as following:  new Firebase failed: First argument must be a valid firebase URL and the path can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]".